# How to explain that this is true or false?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> How to explain this:
>
> $ P(B\mid A)+P(B\mid A^c) ) = 1
> $
>
> Can anyone help me? I can't see how to explain this.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: What other information do you have? Are you sure is not $P(B \mid A) + P(B^c \mid A) = 1$?

Comment: You should not just ask a question and walk away, answering a question requires some times clarification from the OP, as in this case. Please, be more considerate the next time with the people that makes an effort answering and stay tuned at least some minutes after you ask so this kind a things doesn't happen again. Security message: "Don't leave unattended questions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written seems wrong. From total law of probability, 
$P(B\lvert A)+P(B\lvert A^c)=P(B)$

Comment: I am not sure how you would use the total probability law to justify $P(B \mid A)+P(B \mid A^c) = P(B)$, I would like to see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is always true, then provided both $A$ and $\neg A$ happen with non-zero probability, the sum is $2 \not= 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Toss a fair coin once. Let $A$ be the event "head", and let $B$ be the event "neither head nor tail," or, if you prefer, "head or tail."

One can produce more complicated counterexamples.  For a mild variant, let $A$ be as before. Also roll a fair die, and let $B$ be the event the die shows a $6$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
1-P(B|A)=\frac{P(A)-P(AB)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(AB^c)}{P(A)}=P(B^c|A)\ne P(B|A^c)
$$
So it should be
$$
P(B|A)+P(B^c|A)=1
$$